# Creating An Ambient Property That Inherits From a Parent's Property

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

Can't seem to figure out how to do this. I have an inherited Control: **MyControl** with a property called *MyOtherFont*. How do I get *MyOtherFont* to inherit the ambient value of the Parent control's *Font* property?

For example, from the designer if I drag this control onto a Form where the font is Segoe UI, it should inherit that value from the Form and not show it as bolded in the property window.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Here is a C# example that does exactly what my example describes. Hope this helps someone.

```
public class MyControl : Control
{

    private Font myOtherFont;
    public Font MyOtherFont
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.myOtherFont == null)
            {
                if (base.Parent != null)
                    return base.Parent.Font;
            }

            return this.myOtherFont;
        }
        set
        {
            this.myOtherFont = value;
        }
    }

    private bool ShouldSerializeMyOtherFont()
    {
        if (base.Parent != null)
            if (base.Parent.Font.Equals(this.MyOtherFont))
                return false;

        if (this.MyOtherFont == null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    private void ResetMyOtherFont()
    {
        if (base.Parent != null)
            this.MyOtherFont = base.Parent.Font;
        else
            this.MyOtherFont = Control.DefaultFont;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not enough, you also have to give a way to reset the property so it is ambient again.  ResetMyOtherFont() method.  And tell the designer about it, [AmbientValue] attribute.

Comment: @HansPassant I have the ResetMyOtherFont method there. Not sure how the attribute should be used on that property though. Any insight?

Comment: When you get the parent font for the first time, you may want to set the inherited font to the base so you don't have two if statements to check everytime you wish to access it